# I need the below code written as React Hooks. Is it possible to write it so?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using react hooks mostly in my current app. I need the below code expressed as react hooks, without the this.state and this.props. My current app is expressed entirely as React Hooks. If you see it closely, the below code is writing out SQL query code with the click of a button. I need that functionality in my current app, but I don't know how to assimilate that in my app. Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Tabs, Spin, Card, Alert, Tooltip, Icon, Button } from 'antd';
import cubejs from '@cubejs-client/core';
import { QueryRenderer } from '@cubejs-client/react';
import sqlFormatter from "sql-formatter";
import JSONPretty from 'react-json-pretty';
import Prism from "prismjs";
import "./css/prism.css";

const HACKER_NEWS_DATASET_API_KEY = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjozODU5NH0.5wEbQo-VG2DEjR2nBpRpoJeIcE_oJqnrm78yUo9lasw'

class PrismCode extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>
        <code className='language-javascript'>
          { this.props.code }
        </code>
      </pre>
    )
  }
}

const tabList = [{
  key: 'code',
  tab: 'Code'
}, {
  key: 'sqlQuery',
  tab: 'Generated SQL'
}, {
  key: 'response',
  tab: 'Response'
}];

class CodeExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { activeTabKey: 'code' };
  }

  onTabChange(key) {
    this.setState({ activeTabKey: key });
  }

  render() {
    const { codeExample, resultSet, sqlQuery } = this.props;
    const contentList = {
      code: <PrismCode code={codeExample} />,
      response: <PrismCode code={JSON.stringify(resultSet, null, 2)} />,
      sqlQuery: <PrismCode code={sqlQuery && sqlFormatter.format(sqlQuery.sql())} />
    };

    return (<Card
      type="inner"
      tabList={tabList}
      activeTabKey={this.state.activeTabKey}
      onTabChange={(key) => { this.onTabChange(key, 'key'); }}
    >
      { contentList[this.state.activeTabKey] }
    </Card>);
  }
}

const Loader = () => (
  <div style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: "50px" }}>
    <Spin size="large" />
  </div>
)

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showCode: false };
  }

  render() {
    const { query, codeExample, render, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        query={query}
        cubejsApi={cubejs(HACKER_NEWS_DATASET_API_KEY)}
        loadSql
        render={ ({ resultSet, sqlQuery, error, loadingState }) => {
          if (error) {
            return <Alert
              message="Error occured while loading your query"
              description={error.message}
              type="error"
            />
          }

          if (resultSet && !loadingState.isLoading) {
            return (<Card
              title={title || "Example"}
              extra={<Button
                onClick={() => this.setState({ showCode: !this.state.showCode })}
                icon="code"
                size="small"
                type={this.state.showCode ? 'primary' : 'default'}
              >{this.state.showCode ? 'Hide Code' : 'Show Code'}</Button>}
            >
              {render({ resultSet, error })}
              {this.state.showCode && <CodeExample resultSet={resultSet} codeExample={codeExample} sqlQuery={sqlQuery}/>}
            </Card>);
          }

          return <Loader />
        }}
      />
    );
  }
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: If it works, don't worry that it's using classes instead of hooks. If you want to understand how to change something from class-based to hooks, it's better to formulate a more general question, see if it's been asked before (it probably is) but if not then post the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to convert a class to a functional component.

Remember these steps:

1. **class** => **const**

```
  // Class
  export class Example

  // FC
  export const Example
```

2. **componentLifeCycles** => **useEffect**

```
  // Class lifecycle
  componentDidMount() { 
      // logic here 
  } 
  // FC
  useEffect(() => { 
      // logic here 
  })
```

3. **render** => **return**

```
  // Class
  render () { 
    return (<Component/>) 
  } 

  // FC
  return (<Component />)`
```

4. **constructor** => **useState**

```
  // Class
  constructor(props) { 
    this.state.val = props.val 
  }

  // FC
  const [val, setVal] = useState(props.val)
```

5. **setState** => **second arg from useState**

```
  // Class
  constructor() {
    this.state.val = val  // constructor
  }
  this.setState({ val }) // class

  // FC
  const[val, setVal] = useState(null)
  setVal("someVal")
```

---

TLDR: **Solution**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { Tabs, Spin, Card, Alert, Button } from "antd"
import cubejs from "@cubejs-client/core"
import { QueryRenderer } from "@cubejs-client/react"
import sqlFormatter from "sql-formatter"
import Prism from "prismjs"
import "./css/prism.css"

const HACKER_NEWS_DATASET_API_KEY =
  "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjozODU5NH0.5wEbQo-VG2DEjR2nBpRpoJeIcE_oJqnrm78yUo9lasw"

const PrismCode: React.FC = ({ code }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll()
  })

  return (
    <pre>
      <code className="language-javascript">{code}</code>
    </pre>
  )
}


const TabList = [
  {
    key: "code",
    tab: "Code",
  },
  {
    key: "sqlQuery",
    tab: "Generated SQL",
  },
  {
    key: "response",
    tab: "Response",
  },
]


const CodeExample: React.FC = ( { codeExample, resultSet, sqlQuery } ) => {
  const [activeTabKey, setActiveTab] = useState("code")
  
  const onTabChange = (key) => setActiveTab(key)
  
  const contentList = {
    code: <PrismCode code={codeExample} />,
    response: <PrismCode code={JSON.stringify(resultSet, null, 2)} />,
    sqlQuery: (
      <PrismCode code={sqlQuery && sqlFormatter.format(sqlQuery.sql())} />
    ),
  }

  return (
    <Card
      type="inner"
      tabList={TabList}
      activeTabKey={activeTabKey}
      onTabChange={(key) => {
        onTabChange(key)
      }}
    >
      {contentList[activeTabKey]}
    </Card>
  )
}


const Loader = () => (
  <div style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "50px" }}>
    <Spin size="large" />
  </div>
)

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane


const Example: React.FC = ({ query, codeExample, render, title }) => {
  const [showCode, toggleCode] = useState(false)

  return (
    <QueryRenderer
        query={query}
        cubejsApi={cubejs(HACKER_NEWS_DATASET_API_KEY)}
        loadSql
        render={({ resultSet, sqlQuery, error, loadingState }) => {
          if (error) {
            return (
              <Alert
                message="Error occured while loading your query"
                description={error.message}
                type="error"
              />
            )
          }

          if (resultSet && !loadingState.isLoading) {
            return (
              <Card
                title={title || "Example"}
                extra={
                  <Button
                    onClick={() =>
                      toggleCode(!this.state.showCode)
                    }
                    icon="code"
                    size="small"
                    type={showCode ? "primary" : "default"}
                  >
                    {showCode ? "Hide Code" : "Show Code"}
                  </Button>
                }
              >
                {render({ resultSet, error })}
                {showCode && (
                  <CodeExample
                    resultSet={resultSet}
                    codeExample={codeExample}
                    sqlQuery={sqlQuery}
                  />
                )}
              </Card>
            )
          }

          return <Loader />
        }}
      />    
  )
}

export default Example
```